# Issues with upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 17.10

It would be appreciated if somebody helps me!
I upgraded my Ubuntu from 16.04 directly to 17.10 (so there were no Ubuntu 17.04 in middle).

After upgrading, my Ubuntu does not look like Ubuntu 17.10 at all (I do not have those new features): for instance, I can not see the calendar in the middle upper part of my screen. Or the way I should close a window is like before (In new Ubuntu 17.10 you should be able to close the windows like windows from the right side of the window. Right?) and etc.

When I am checking the version of my installed Ubuntu, it is Ubuntu 17.10, but actually, it is not!

And, just for the record, after I restart my computer, I have to option to log in:

```
Unity
Ubuntu Xorg
```

I only can log in with the first one! Ubuntu Xorg does not work for me :(

I attached a screenshot of my desktop to this message here:

[image]

Comment: How did you perform the upgrade?  Also, were you running Unity before the upgrade?  You are still running Ubuntu 17.10 but with the Unity Desktop.  If you want those features, look into installing GNOME http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/10/install-vanilla-gnome-shell-ubuntu-17-10